# Error in mclapply(., function(x) { : 'mc.cores' > 1 is not supported on Windows

Tags: r

How do I use this line in windows?

````
mclapply(.,
           function(x) {filter_taxa(x, function(y) sum(y) > 0, TRUE)},
           mc.cores = nrow(params_2)) -> # remove 0-summed ASVs
  Ps_obj_SIP_each_rep_l```

I need to replace mclapply and mc.cores to a proper function in windows.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mclapply()` does the same as lapply, but over multiple cores. So to refactor it to work without parallelization, simply try this;

```r
lapply(., function(x) {filter_taxa(x, function(y) sum(y) > 0, TRUE)})
```

See more in the [mclapply docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/parallel/versions/3.4.0/topics/mclapply):

> `mclapply` is a parallelized version of `lapply`,